Add nonce tag to Html.Kendo().DatePicker() script
I am working to remove 'unsafe-inline' and 'unsafe-eval' from our CSP. For this I am getting an error that we cannot run the inline script for the datepicker. In the page we have code like this:
<div class="col-xs-1 text-right padding-top-1">
    From:
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    @(Html.Kendo().DatePicker()
      .Name("fromDate")
      .Events(e => e.Change("startChange"))
      .Format("MM/dd/yyyy")
    )
</div>`

and it generates this in the page:
<div class="col-xs-1 text-right padding-top-1">
    From:
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <input id="fromDate" name="fromDate" type="date" />
        <script>
            jQuery(function(){jQuery("#fromDate").kendoDatePicker({"change":startChange,"format":"MM/dd/yyyy","min":new Date(1900,0,1,0,0,0,0),"max":new Date(2099,11,31,0,0,0,0)});});
        </script>
</div>

does anyone know how I can get this to generate with the script tag like this:
<script nonce='Random-1'>
    //some code for date picker
</script>

I am completely stuck on how to approach this, we want to avoid a method to include all the hashes in the CSP
